# How to allow only numbers between 0 to 30 or A,D character in input using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have created a javascript function to only allow numbers between 0 to 30 and character A and D. I give an alert if it does not match the criteria but if the user clicks ok on the alert the values still remain in the input and can be updated in the database. I want that user should not be able to enter anything at all in the input box except character A , D and numbers between 0 to 30 like it is done in the case of input type=number we can only enter numbers. My javascript function is:-

```
function validate() {
    var regex = /[ad0-9]/gi;
    var txt = document.getElementById('txt').value;
    var valid = true;
    var error = '';
    if (regex.test(txt)) {
        if (!isNaN(txt)) {
            if (!(parseInt(txt) >= 0 && parseInt(txt) <= 30)) {
                valid = false;
                error = 'Please enter between 0 to 30.'
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        valid = false;
        error = 'Please enter between 0 to 30, A or D'
    }

    if (!valid) {
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

The javascript works fine with validation but after clicking ok in alert value still remains there and it also gives error when input box is empty any way to avoid that. Is there any other better way to create the function or can it done by using jquery. I am new to jquery if it is possible to do it with jquery it would be great. I would be highly gratefull if anybody can help.

Comment: You can make the input box required :)

Comment: What is the order of input `char-num` or `num-char`?

Comment: @Arvind The input will be either characters or numbers b/w 0 to 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this code example.

```js
function validate(box) {
  var val = box.value;
  if (!/^[AD]?$/.test(val) && isNaN(val) || (0 > val || 30 < val)) {
    box.value = '';
    alert('Only A or D or 0-30');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type='text' value='30' onblur='validate(this);' />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(txt.replace(/ /g, '').length == 0) {
    // text is empty
    return; // get out of function
}
```

If you want to make sure there is no error when the text is empty, you can do this. The `.replace` part is to ensure that if the text input is filled with only spaces, it is considered empty.

With the rest of the function:

```
function validate() {
    var regex = /[ad0-9]/gi;
    var txt = document.getElementById('txt').value;
    var valid = true;
    var error = '';
    if(txt.replace(/ /g, '').length == 0) {
        // text is empty
        return; // get out of function
    }
    if (regex.test(txt)) {
        if (!isNaN(txt)) {
            if (!(parseInt(txt) >= 0 && parseInt(txt) <= 30)) {
                valid = false;
                error = 'Please enter between 0 to 30.'
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        valid = false;
        error = 'Please enter between 0 to 30, A or D'
    }

    if (!valid) {
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should these if statement should be placed. Can you please integrate it with the whole function.

Comment: Thank you it is working for no alert on no input but what about not even allowing values that do not match the criteria.

Comment: @KartikeyVishwakarma Hmm sorry I don't do much regex, probably won't be able to help :/ My solution is only for no alert on no input. For not allowing values that do not match the criteria, maybe see another answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to check it at the moment when you are inserting it in the database.

Comment: Is there no way to limit the values matching the regex only are entered in the input with javascript.

Comment: Yes but one can make a request to the submission page using for example curl; without even using your javascript frontend; so the best practice is to check the input before inserting it in the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing disallowed values so only the desired input is allowed.  With this you won't be able to enter anything other than A, D and numbers 0 - 30:

```js
$('input').on('input', function(e) {
  this.value = this.value
    .replace(/[^AD\d]/, '')
    .replace(/(3)[1-9]/, '$1')
    .replace(/(30)[0-9]/, '$1')
    .replace(/([4-9])[0-9]/, '$1')
    .replace(/([\d][\d])[\d]/, '$1');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Note, it's still a good idea to do some server side validation.

Comment: The input is accepting values greater than 30 as well. I can enter 99 as well in the input.

Comment: And what if it needs to be changed dynamically through database i some case maximum values can be 24. What all needs to be changed then.

Comment: well i fixed the regex so that will work as it should now.  to answer your question "what if..." i only answered the question as you posted it.  you never mentioned anything about needing this to be dynamic.  if you need to change the rules, change the regex.